# What are Santilli's isonumbers?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

A friend of mine asked me yesterday about Santilli's isonumbers. I told him that it was quackery. As I based my answer only on the general reputation of the guy and had no knowledge of the subject, I decided to ask this question here.

Question: What is the isonumber? Did any serious mathematician spend any time looking at isomnumbers? What is the conclusion? References would be useful.

Comment: I have no idea of what you are talking about, but a little research with google says www.i-b-r.org/docs/jiang.pdf, that seems something like a monograph.

Comment: «Despite the achievement of the above epoch making generalizations of all pre-existing mathematical and physical theories [...]» That alone surely will get you a high Baez index... 

Comment: Good to know:    http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/crackpot.html 
see also  http://www.drbronner.com/  

Comment: See http://www.sptimes.com/2007/05/09/Hillsborough/Snubbed_by_mainstream.shtml before answering this question

Comment: @ Richard Good Warning! Although he seems to be more keen on his physical theories...

Comment: A good review paper: Kadeisvili, J. V. “[An Introduction to The Lie–Santilli Isotopic Theory](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/%28SICI%291099-1476%2819961125%2919:17%3C1349::AID-MMA823%3E3.0.CO;2-B/abstract).” _Mathematical Methods in the Applied Sciences_ 19, no. 17 (November 25, 1996): 1349–95.  ([non-paywalled version](http://www.santilli-foundation.org/docs/Santilli-30.pdf))

Comment: There's also a semi-popular-level introduction: Corda, Christian. “[Introduction to Santilli Iso-Numbers](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/proceeding/aipcp/10.1063/1.4756316).” In _AIP Conference Proceedings_, 1479:1013–15. AIP Publishing, 2012. ([non-paywalled version](http://www.santilli-foundation.org/docs/Corda-iso-mathematics.pdf))

Comment: Santilli's isonumbers result from his study of [Lie-admissible algebras](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Lie-admissible_algebra), which the American mathematician [Abraham A. Albert](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/history/Mathematicians/Albert_Abraham.html) discovered: A.A. Albert, "[Power associative rings](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1990399)" Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. , 64 (1948) pp. 552–593.

Comment: Here's a recent, thorough, formal introduction: Ganfornina, Raúl M. Falcón, and Juan Núñez Valdés. “[**Mathematical Foundations of Santilli Isotopies**](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/276269128_Mathematical_Foundations_of_Santilli_Isotopies).” Translated by Alan Aversa. [_Algebras, Groups, and Geometries_](http://www.hadronicpress.com/index.php?p=AGGE) **32** (2015): 135–308.

Answer (score 10):

I looked at Jiang's monograph for a little while last night.  Here is what I could get from it (I am now quoting from memory, so my terminology and notation may not be exactly the same).  If $F$ is a field (of "numbers"), then the field $\overline{F}$ of "isodual numbers" has the same underlying set and addition operation, but multiplication is replaced by the operation $x \ \overline{\bullet}\  y := - (xy)$.  The new multiplicative identity is $-1$.

This is mathematically valid, of course: i.e., $\overline{F}$ really is a field.  Moreover it is isomorphic to $F$ via the map $x \mapsto -x$, although I couldn't find a clear statement of that.  (But somewhat later on I saw references to the **isotopy** $F \rightarrow \overline{F}$.)  Physically speaking, the isodual numbers are supposed to bear the same relation to the ordinary numbers as antimatter does to matter.  (I don't know what that means, but I am not a physicist and so am not even going to worry about it.)

Jiang defines a new function $J_2(\omega)$, which is supposed to be some sort of repaired version of the Riemann zeta function.  In one of his published works, he claims that the Riemann hypothesis is false -- in fact, he says, the zeta function has no zeros in the critical strip.  [Logically speaking, wouldn't that make the Riemann Hypothesis *true*?  Never mind.]  From this definition, he immediately deduces proofs of Goldbach, twin primes, primes of the form $n^2+1$, and several other outstanding number theoretic conjectures -- literally immediately, in that I could find no argumentation for them.  First these results are stated for "isonumbers" but later on they are stated for the usual integers.

That's about as far as I got.  I also noticed, though, that many of the results described in this monograph were first published as papers by the journal **Algebra, Groups and Geometries** (founding editor: R.M. Santilli).  These papers appear on MathSciNet but are not (going to be) reviewed.

Comment: I have read Jiang's book today and this is a definite quackery. I have managed to google http://www.fprotheory.com/showthread.php?p=206  He seems to be some kind of "mathematician of the people" in China:-))

I wish I could get hold of Santilli's 1993 paper in Algebras, Groups and Geometries...

Comment: I found his papers with a couple of friends when I was an undergrad and we had some fun browsing through them. If I interpret his "disproof" of the Riemann hypothesis correctly, he starts using the definition $\zeta(s)=\Prod(1-\frac{1}{p^s})$ as if it converged for $\Re(s)<1$, makes a lot of estimates, and concludes that $|\zeta(s)|>C$ for a nonzero constant $C$ --- but, of course, he gets that because the series he is using as a definition is not convergent.

Comment: @BugsBunny Here's his 1993 paper: R. M. Santilli, "[Isonumbers and Genonumbers of Dimensions 1, 2, 4, 8, their Isoduals and Pseudoduals, and Hidden Numbers of Dimension 3, 5, 6, 7](http://www.santilli-foundation.org/docs/Santilli-34.pdf)" [_Algebras, Groups and Geometries_](http://hadronicpress.com/) Vol. 10, 273 (1993).

Comment: Here's a recent, thorough, formal introduction: Ganfornina, Raúl M. Falcón, and Juan Núñez Valdés. “[**Mathematical Foundations of Santilli Isotopies**](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/276269128_Mathematical_Foundations_of_Santilli_Isotopies).” Translated by Alan Aversa. [_Algebras, Groups, and Geometries_](http://www.hadronicpress.com/index.php?p=AGGE) **32** (2015): 135–308.